# Are questions about elementary OS off topic even if it's about the kernel?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

I'm currently on Xubuntu and I'm so happy with it, but I want to try Elementary OS, I do know that if I ask something about Elementary OS my question will be closed. I'm well aware of that. Elementary OS is not Ubuntu.

But if I ask something related to the kernel, like "What driver do I need to connect Broadcom" or "How to uninstall software manager?" or "issues with the sound drivers etc"

And if I do mention that I am on 13.04 which is a kernel version, will my question be closed? After all, those questions have to deal with Ubuntu kernel regardless of the distro being used.

The thing is, I would like to try Elementary OS, but I do want to still be able to participate in this community. I used manjaro, crunchbang, mint, fuduntu and many more. I dumped them all and went for xubuntu, not because I like it. I hate that heavy beast, but because I wanted to get help when I need it.

Unix.stackoverflow is great and I do go there from time to time, but it's not as active as here. Superuser is superb, I love it, but it's more Windows oriented. Elementary OS forums are young, not so active. Therefore, I want to make sure that I can still come here and be active before going for Elementary OS Luna.

Comment: An important factor for me when deciding which OS to use is the support from the respective community. I don't know if it's a good idea to have it both ways.

Comment: It wasn't around when this was posted, but now there is [a Stack Exchange site for elementary OS](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @EliahKagan yeah i noticed, im now on fedora, maybe a fedora se will be created in 3 years

Comment: Although it's not a Stack Exchange site, an [Ask Fedora](https://ask.fedoraproject.org/en/questions/) question-answer site exists and it's one of Fedora's official support resources (listed under "support" near the bottom of https://getfedora.org/). Besides that, Fedora is fully on-topic at [unix.se].

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For that exist [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/), that is the correct place to ask about Linux not Ubuntu. Here we have a very scoped scope, Ubuntu. If you have a question about anything else that is not Ubuntu or **official derivatives** there's [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) for Linux specific problems and [Super User](https://superuser.com/) for everything else D:

Comment: I know that, I already mention it, besides, if I lie and say I am running ubuntu and I am not, what do you care? you could answer the "ubuntu way" for example, how could you tell that now I am running xubuntu? maybe I'm lying to you. You see the point :)

Comment: @Fischer remember that the only thing that you have online is your online reputation. If you lose *your* reputation online people might not answer your questions just because you don't give the whole picture or they won't trust you are giving them all the information. UL has nice guys, they have many experienced users in the most elemental topics about Linux. If your question is something general you will be sure that will get better answers there, also you have the most to lose if we discover that you lied to us.

Comment: That policy is worst than arch forums, if you been there you know what i mean :) anyway, I tried elementary and didn't detect my wifi drivers so I'll stick to xubuntu and [install pantheon](http://askubuntu.com/questions/66757/how-do-i-install-the-pantheon-desktop-environment), that's the smartest solution: staying with the OS that is working on my machine - getting the DE that I like - still getting support here - running 13.10 not lts which is installed on elementary - win win situation